# VPN server acting as a client for another VPN server

Tags: vpn, network, networking

I was wondering if it's possible to have a VPN server that goes though another VPN server.

Here a scenario that might explain my idea better: I have 4 computers

1. '**A**' - My Windows machine
2. '**B**' - My VPN server (pptp)
3. '**C**' - My client's VPN server (pptp)
4. '**D**' - My client's windows machine

All of them are in different networks except of the **C** and **D** - they're on the same network.

Currently, what I have to do to connect to **D** is to connect to their VPN first (**C**) and then I can connect to the **D**.

My question is: Can I somehow set up the **B** to act as a server for me but as a client for the **C**? So I could just connect from **A** to **B** and then straight to **D** (Because **B** VPN is always connected to the **C** VPN)

This scenario is simplified and I know it wouldn't make sense to do such thing in this specific scenario, but I have many clients, that require VPNs and some of them use white-listing, and I was wondering if I can set this kind of a hub, that will handle all the VPNs for me.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is off topic here. You can consider asking this on [su] for a personal setup or on [sf] for an enterprise setup.

Comment: @TeunVink Thanks for your suggestion, however I don't see how this question is off-topic. I believe it does fit one of the topics listed in the help center - "design or theory of protocols used to operate a network (e.g. IP, TCP, routing protocols, STP, etc)". 
I didn't list any hardware I am using, because I'm still in the process of planning, and this was a theoretical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible? Yes, definitely - either directly on the VPN server or routed in your network to another VPN terminator. At work, we use a mix of static IPsec (for branch locations), dynamic IPsec (for VoIP phones), and SSL VPN (for roaming clients), all routed in between as required.

Basically, you just have to create a 2nd VPN connection and route in between them. This of course requires all participants to have the necessary routes for their tunnel(s), e.g. your client's end C needs to know how to route to your machine A.

How this can be set up depends on your equipment and its already present configuration - note that host configurations are off-topic on NE. If you're using on-topic equipment you'll need to add the details to your question (make, model, sanitized config, possibly a network diagram).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was thinking about using a Raspberry Pi (wanted to go cheap) for the B (my own pptp vpn server) but I'm not sure what server my client has. I understand that I can't really have a real connection to the D from A by just setting up B as a client for C because C wouldn't know how to talk to A - it would be just talking to the B. Could you tell me how I could sort that issue out? How do I tell the B: "Oh, hi! This packet needs to go to the A" 
(I'm not asking for the exact steps, but just a direction to help me find the answer)

Comment: For the remote networks, you'll need to set up routes pointing to the VPN/tunnel interfaces. However, host configurations and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.